# jQuery-UI draggable: div doesn't follow mouse correctly horizontal

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable

Here is a short [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tmuecksch/RErSF/6/). I want to make a dialog draggable. It is horizontal centered via css the following way:

```
div.dialog-container {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
```

My dialog contains a header and a content div. The whole dialog is to be dragged around by dragging the header. So i used the jQuery-UI .draggable() widget like this:

```
$("div.dialog-container").draggable({
    handle: "div.dialog-header"
});
```

**The Problem is:** dragging the dialog around works but not the way it is intended to. Vertically the dialog follows the mouse perfect ***but horizontally it follows the mouse too slow*** so it is possible to leave the dialog while dragging around *(for example click on the header on the very right and drag the dialog to the right*). **The interesting thing is:** Removing "margin: auto;" fixes the problem but the element is not centered anymore. Centering the div with javascript is no option.
Do you have any ideas on how to fix that problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your dialog has a fixed width, try

```
left: 50%;
margin: auto;
margin-left: -200px;
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hRCQ4/1/)

Comment: Your demo doesn't work for me. It still doesn't follow the mouse correctly...?

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RErSF/7/)**</kbd>

```
div.dialog-container {
    height: 250px;
    width: 400px;   
    border: 1px solid black;   
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;             /*   center   */
    margin-left:-200px;    /*   width/2   */
    top: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This solution worked. I'm gonna accept this answer as soon stack overflow allows me to.

Comment: @roXon, I loved the way you made `LIVE DEMO`

Comment: @Jashwant thanks you're free to use and abuse... I just love button styles ;)

Comment: Yeah, the first thing I did is hit the 'edit' to see the markdown code :P